# Filtering twilio messages my sent data,

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, twilio

I'm trying to filter my Twilio messages in Laravel by the data. This is my current code to retrieve sent messages.

```
 $sentMessages = $twilio->messages
                     ->read(array(
                             "from" => "+353861802205",
                             "to" => $user->phone,
                             'DateSent>=' => new \DateTime('2018-08-23')
                         )
                     );
```

I have also tried  `'DateSent>' => '2018-08-23'`

Any idea how to filter these messages correctly.

Comment: does `$twilio->messages->read` return `Collection` ?

Comment: It does. I need to loop through it access each message.

Answer (score 0):

If `$twilio->messages->read()` return Collection then you can filter it like this

```
$sentMessages = $twilio->messages
                     ->read()
                     ->where([
                        ['from', '+353861802205'],
                        ['to', $user->phone],
                        ['DateSent', '>=', '2018-08-23']
                     ])->all();
```